# Cursed logic or my copy-paste macro is working wrong?

Tags: excel, vba

So few days ago I had an issue with macro, but couldn't really fix it with community help, so I used feedback to write another one from scraps, however it is still not working (as it copies no data), even though I believe it has better logic. So what it was intended to do: open two workbooks using paths from active workbook, workbooks are actually same to the names of worksheets, only data changes. Next macro identifies if the worksheet has Status column and if yes finds ID column. Then it finds the worksheet with the same name in second workbook and compares data in the row with same ID, if status changed from NO to YES, the row from second workbook is copied to the active workbook.

```
Sub CompareRows()
    Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook, wb3 As Workbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, wsComp As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow1 As Long, lastRow2 As Long
    Dim compareValue As String
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, m As Long, s As Long
    Dim idCol1 As Long, statusCol1 As Long
    Dim fileA1 As String, fileA2 As String
    

    fileA1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Compare").Range("A1").Value
    fileA2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Compare").Range("A2").Value
    

    Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & fileA1)
    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & fileA2)
    Set wb3 = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsComp = wb3.Sheets("Compare")
    

    wsComp.Rows("4:" & wsComp.Rows.Count).ClearContents
    

    For Each ws1 In wb1.Worksheets
        idCol1 = 0
        statusCol1 = 0
        

        For s = 1 To ws1.Cells(1, ws1.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            If ws1.Cells(1, s).Value = "Status" Then
                statusCol1 = s
                If statusCol1 > 0 Then
                    For m = 1 To ws1.Cells(1, ws1.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
                        If ws1.Cells(1, m).Value = "ID marker" Or ws1.Cells(1, m).Value = "ID value" Then
                            idCol1 = m
                        End If
                    Next m
                End If
            End If
            If idCol1 > 0 And statusCol1 > 0 Then Exit For
        Next s
        

        On Error Resume Next
        Set ws2 = wb2.Sheets(ws1.Name)
        On Error GoTo 0
        
        If Not ws2 Is Nothing Then
 
            lastRow1 = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            lastRow2 = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            

            For i = 2 To lastRow1
                compareValue = ws1.Cells(i, idCol1)
                For j = 2 To lastRow2
                    If ws2.Cells(j, "A").Value = compareValue Then
                        If ws1.Cells(i, "B").Value = "No" And ws2.Cells(j, "B").Value = "Yes" Then
                            k = wsComp.Cells(wsComp.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
                            ws2.Rows(j).Copy Destination:=wsComp.Rows(k)
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    End If
                Next j
            Next i
        End If
    Next ws1
    

    wb1.Close SaveChanges:=False
    wb2.Close SaveChanges:=False
    MsgBox "Analysis complete.", vbInformation
End Sub
```

Compared to previous macro, I changed logic, maybe it's the point of issue?

Comment: You've told us what you did, and what you want to happen. You have not explained a problem of any kind with the code you've posted, and you have not asked a specific question related to that code. You may want to review [ask], and then [edit] your question so that we know what the problem is and what you're asking us.

Comment: @KenWhite It may not be that obvious, but I mentioned that macro is not working at all. Locals shows me that everything was identified correctly, but nothing is copied on the list

Comment: *it is not working* is not a problem description. You're going to need to be clear and descriptive, and ask a specific question. What happens when you step through the code in the debugger? What does that tell you? What part of it runs, and what part doesn't? For the part that didn't run, why not? What condition caused it not to run? A test that didn't pass? A condition that wasn't met? A variable or counter with the wrong value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I made it work! Yea, I know guys, that the problem was "It DoEsN't WoRk" and I am sorry for not being specific, but i didn't really know what the issue was. So apart from bettering code, I added

```
 If Not idCol1 > 0 Then Exit For
 If Not statusCol1 > 0 Then Exit For
```

into ws2 loop and it made this pile of commands and variables work the way it was intended

```
Sub CompareRows()
    Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook, wb3 As Workbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, wsComp As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow1 As Long, lastRow2 As Long, lastRowComp1 As Long, lastRowComp2 As Long
    Dim compareValue As String
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, m As Long, s As Long
    Dim idCol1 As Long, statusCol1 As Long
    Dim fileA1 As String, fileA2 As String
    
    fileA1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Compare").Range("A1").Value
    fileA2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Compare").Range("A2").Value
    
    Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & fileA1)
    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & fileA2)
    Set wb3 = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsComp = wb3.Sheets("Compare")
    
    wsComp.Rows("3:" & wsComp.Rows.Count).ClearContents
    wsComp.Rows("3:" & wsComp.Rows.Count).ClearFormats
    
    For Each ws1 In wb1.Worksheets
        idCol1 = 0
        statusCol1 = 0
        
        For s = 1 To ws1.Cells(1, ws1.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            If ws1.Cells(1, s).Value = "Status" Then
                statusCol1 = s
                If statusCol1 > 0 Then
                    For m = 1 To ws1.Cells(1, ws1.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
                        If ws1.Cells(1, m).Value = "ID value" Or ws1.Cells(1, m).Value = "ID marker" Then
                            idCol1 = m
                        End If
                    Next m
                End If
            End If
            If idCol1 > 0 And statusCol1 > 0 Then Exit For
        Next s
        
        For Each ws2 In wb2.Worksheets
            If ws1.Name = ws2.Name Then
                On Error Resume Next
                
                If Not ws2 Is Nothing Then
                If Not idCol1 > 0 Then Exit For
                If Not statusCol1 > 0 Then Exit For
                    lastRowComp1 = wsComp.Cells(wsComp.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
                    wsComp.Cells(wsComp.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = "Sheet: " & ws2.Name

                    k = wsComp.Cells(wsComp.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
                    ws2.Rows(1).Copy Destination:=wsComp.Rows(k)
                    k = k + 1
                    lastRow1 = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
                    lastRow2 = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

                    For i = 2 To lastRow1
                        compareValue = ws1.Cells(i, idCol1)
                    
                        For j = 2 To lastRow2
                            If ws2.Cells(j, idCol1).Value = compareValue Then
                                If ws1.Cells(i, statusCol1).Value = "No" And ws2.Cells(j, statusCol1).Value = "Yes" Then

                                    ws2.Rows(j).Copy Destination:=wsComp.Rows(k)
                                    k = k + 1
                                   
                                    Exit For
                                End If
                            End If
                        Next j
                    Next i
                End If
                On Error GoTo 0
            End If
        Next ws2
        lastRowComp2 = wsComp.Cells(wsComp.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        If lastRowComp2 - lastRowComp1 < 3 And lastRowComp2 >= 4 Then
            wsComp.Rows(lastRowComp2 - 1 & ":" & lastRowComp2).Delete
        End If
    Next ws1

    wb1.Close SaveChanges:=False
    wb2.Close SaveChanges:=False
    MsgBox "Analysis complete.", vbInformation
End Sub
```